# Llenar Datagridview Con Dos Listas c#

Tags: c#, lista, datagrid, objeto

tengo un problema y me preguntaba si alguien podría guiarme.
Tengo dos listas de diferentes tipo Objeto o entidad (List< Entidad A>, List < Entidad B> b) que comparten un mismo campo (IdLista), mi pregunta es como podria llenar un Datagrid con las dos listas y que coincidan los valores. 
A continuación dejo un ejemplo del contenido de la lista.

```
Lista A                                Lista B
-Id Estudiante                        -Id Estudiante 
- Fecha Registro Estudiante           - Nota Materia
- Nombre Estudiante                   - Nombre Materia
```

El grid quedaría algo como:

```
|Id| Nombre| Fecha | Materia | Nota|
```

Lo Anterior solo es un ejemplo

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas suele acabar cerradas, te recomiendo que pongas el código con lo que has intentado

Comment: Lo que intente fue crear un Datatable y llenarlo con ambas listas peguntando con una Expresión Lambda si el Id era igual que me seleccionara los campos que necesitaba con un First(). (Where, Select,  First())  pero asumía que había un método mas optimo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `Linq` de la siguiente forma:

Suponiendo que los objetos están creados así:

```
class ObjetoA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
class ObjetoB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Nota { get; set; }
    public string NombreMateria { get; set; }
}
```

Consulta `Linq`:

```
listaB.Join(listaA, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new { ObjetoA = x, ObjetoB = y }).ToList().ForEach(z =>
{
    datagridview.Rows.Add(z.ObjetoA.IdEstudiante.ToString(), z.ObjetoA.NombreEstudiante, z.ObjetoA.Fecha.ToString(), z.ObjetoB.NombreMateria, z.ObjetoB.Nota.ToString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a crear un tercer tipo de datos que sera al que bindaras el datagrid. Este tipo nuevo debe contener la información que se mostrara en el grid.

Luego puedes crear una tercera lista / IEnumerable que será la que bindaras al grid. Esta tercera lista la rellenas con los datos de las dos listas anteriores.

Utilizando linq puedes seleccionar los elementos de la lista A transformarlos a la nuevo tipo y juntar los datos.

```
var list3 = new List<EntidadC>();

list3.AddRange(listaA.Select(elemento --> ConvertirAEntidadC(elemento)));
list3.AddRange(listaB.Select(elemento --> ConvertirAEntidadC(elemento)));
```